# Solving ODEs with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I've just started trying out SymPy. Unfortunately, I am already stumped. Behold this:

```
from sympy import *
t, G, M = symbols('t G M', real = True)
x = Function('x')
y = Function('y')
print(Eq(Derivative(x, t, 2),  G * M * x(t) / (x(t) * x(t) + y(t) * y(t))**1.5))
```

...it simply prints `False`. The [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.relational.Equality) says that this means the relationship can be *proven* to be false.
I know that I can prevent evaluation by using `evaluation = False`, but eventually I want to solve my system of differential equations, and then this assumption will come into play again.

So, can anyone see what I did wrong here?

**Addendum:**

What I am trying to do is play around with the two-body-problem and orbital mechanics. With the gravitational constant `G` and the mass of the primary `M` at the origin, this and the symmetric equation for `y(t)` describe the gravitational acceleration on the secondary.

The solution, Kepler tells us, should be an ellipse for reasonable starting conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I found it now, the solution is rather simple: `SymPy` needs to be told the `x` is a function of `t`, so

```
print(Eq(Derivative(x(t), t, 2),  G * M * x(t) / (x(t) * x(t) + y(t) * y(t))**1.5))
```

does the trick.